# How to run Dotnet run in background on windows server from Teamcity build step

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, teamcity

In a integrationtest running on Teamcity I am trying to

- Launch a ASPNET Core app using dotnet run
- Run Integration test
- Stop webserver

Using powershell I am then trying to run the webserver in the background using

```
start-job -name someName -scriptblock {dotnet run}
```

But this just gives me

> 16     someName BackgroundJob   Completed True localhost  dotnet run

But the webserver is not running and no error is outputtet

Is there another way to launch a kestrel server in the background using dotnet command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution

But swapped to using the compiled version of the webserver instead of dotnet run

Doing this to launch my webserver build step

```
Start-Process .\someName.exe -NoNewWindow -PassThru
```

**Run tests**

And this to end it

```
Stop-Process -name YourServiceName
```

Works

Comment: From where does it take the name AGPService?

Comment: If you start it with Start-Process .\someName.exe -NoNewWindow -PassThru then your service will have some name, mine is named AGPService

Comment: Start-Process .\AGPService.exe -NoNewWindow -PassThru is what I used

Comment: Got it. Once you start it, it tells you the service name as well. Thanks :)